# Change Schema Name at Runtime in data context

Tags: c#, oracle, devart, dotconnect

So, I'm using [dotConnect for Oracle](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/).  I used the template and wizard to create a model of the database (Database first approach).  We have multiple databases that a single application needs to reference and unfortunately the schema naming which contain the tables are not uniform across the other databases.

In the auto generated class in the `Designer.cs` file I get:

```
[Table(Name = @"FMC_TP.EQUIPMENT")]
```

But considering which database connection the schema could be:

```
[Table(Name = @"FMC_DEV.EQUIPMENT"]
```

Is there a way to change the schema for the mapping at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle you can call `alter session set current_schema = SCHEMA_NAME` statement which set contex of your session. Then you can go without prefixing tables with schema name but this may help only if you're using same session for all statements.

Comment: I'm using 4 different schema at the same time.  So I guess I would need to change each time I create a session.  It's worth a shot.

Comment: @FelixCastor Yes if in one session you use tables from differen schemas you need to execute the command multiple times but it allows you to keep table names without schema names and dynamically set them by executing multiple `alter`

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone has a similar issue I will expand on Kacper's answer:

In the model file `MyModel.lqml` I removed the schema specifications from the table names:

```
<Table Name="SCHEMA.TABLE" Member="ModelTableName">
```

to

```
<Table Name="TABLE" Member="ModelTableName">
```

Basiscally where applicable.

In code:

```
MyModelDataContext mycontext = new MyModelDataContext();

mycontext.ExecuteCommand($"ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = {Schema}", new object[1]);
```

Then perform my query.

```
            var rows = from x in mycontext.ModelTableName
                            where x.COLUMN == id
                            select x;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an additional way to execute a command immediately after establishing a connection: set command (or several commands) via Run Once Command (or Initialization Command) connection string parameter. For more information, refer to https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/docs/?Devart.Data.Oracle~Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleConnection~ConnectionString.html.